# JAVA WorldWind LayerTree with Radio Buttons

Tags: java, checkbox, radio-button, worldwind

WorldWind LayerTree uses checkboxes for default configuration. Is there any way to change checkboxes to radio-buttons?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arNgB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any solution for replacing check boxes with radio-buttons. So, I decided to try another approach and it works for me. I catch the property change event of LayerTree and reset the selected nodes other than the newly selected one.

```
LayerTree layerTree = new LayerTree();
layerTree.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {   
        for (Iterator<TreeNode> treeNode = layerTree.getModel().getRoot().getChildren().iterator(); treeNode.hasNext(); ) {
               LayerTreeNode layerTreeNode = LayerTreeNode.class.cast(treeNode.next());
               if(evt.getSource() instanceof LayerTreeNode && evt.getSource() != layerTreeNode)
                layerTreeNode.setSelected(false);
        }       
    }       
});
```